# How can i use my headset for listening but using laptop built-in microphone to record my voice?

Tags: linux, audio, xubuntu, recording, audacity

In windows it's very easy. How come in linux there is no solution?

I have already tried using hda-jack-retask, but it was updated in 2014 last time and now its 2020 with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. A lot has changed.

So i tried it out (hda-jack-retask), which seemed to work but messed up with my Xfce4 desktop, and audacity was buggy/crashing/doing weird stuff.

Never any of this happened before i use starting hdajackretask.

Also i cant change the settings in PulseAudio control, becuase if i plug in my headset, the built in mic is automatically unplugged. There is no option to do this.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

> Also i cant change the settings in PulseAudio control, becuase if i
> plug in my headset, the built in mic is automatically unplugged. There
> is no option to do this.

Have you tried configuring the mixer control *after* plugging in the microphone/headphones set ?

I haven't been using Ubuntu in a long time but I think there used to be a specific differentiation in PulseAudio between sound cards and the whole lot of devices that would allow to do what you seek - yet not to make it permanent, I suspect. That's half the trouble.